# What is the best way to use mysql server with docker?

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a golang web application associated with MySQL database. I need to deploy that web application in number of servers provided by different vendors. So I am going to used docker images to deploy this web app. The thing I need to know is, it is okay to keep Mysql server on same docker image or should I make a separate docker image to deploy MySQL on those servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rule of thumb with Docker which you should follow is "One application, one container" It's always the best practice to have separate containers for different parts of your application. The main reason is that down the line if you want to replace MySQL with some NoSQL database, you could simply kill the container and spin up a new one and not worry about it affecting your golang application